# How to print to file through an ip address or virtual parallel port

Tags: windows-8, printing

I have an old application that will only print to either a parallel port or ip.

I just want to print to file though... is there a print driver that will intercept jobs coming to a virtual parallel port or ip address and print them to file without me having to actually have a printer?

Comment: Which OS? Version? Any other pertinent info?

Comment: Can you advise your OS and environment ?  That is pretty important to finding you a solution.

Comment: @davidgo Oops! Yes that's extremely important and I can't believe I forgot to tag it: Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Create a printer that uses "FILE:" as the port. You may want to use the [Generic/Text Only driver](http://www.kbytes.co.uk/Articles.asp?articleid=58). Share that printer, even if you will be the only user. Make a note of the share name you give it.

Then, from a DOS prompt type the following command:

NET USE LPT1: \computer_name\printer_share_name /PERSISTENT:YES

If you don't know how to open a command prompt in Win 8, look [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/command-prompt-windows-8.htm).

This will prompt you for a file name and location when you print. If you always want to use the same file, create a new Local Port for the printer (instead of selecting FILE:), with the file name & location. You won't be prompted then.